Best practice to trigger a child of a child-component in Blazor Webassembly
Ok after struggling with this issue for the better part of a whole day, it's time to ask some grownups.
This is written in .net 8 Blazor Webassembly, and we are using a standard CRUD API to store the data. So after the initial render no data is handled serverside. It's all client and API.
The short story is that I have a ListItem component in blazor-webassembly that needs to update, but I can't figure out how to invalidate on specific ListItem component when data changes in the Model.
So lets say this is my datamodel:
public class HouseModel {
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Parents { get; } 
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; }
}

public class PersonModel {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Parent { get; set; }
}

Then I have a class to enforce some rules as well as autosave everything to an API:
public class HouseEditor {
    public Task SetHouseNumber(int houseId, int houseNumber) { ... }
    public Task SetPersonName(int personId, string name) { ... }
    public Task SetParent(int personId, bool isParent) { ... }
}

And lastly I have some blazor components, I'll just pseudo-code here to shorten this message somewhat
House.blazor:
    - Show the HouseNumber as <input>, and call HouseEditor.SetHouseNumber() if the housenumber is changed by the user
    - Show all the parents of the house, and react dynamically to any changes in the persons living in the house.
    - List all the persons using a separate component PersonList

PersonList.blazor:
    - Show a summary of the people in the house, this means the number of people, the number of parents, and the oldest person.
    - foreach person in the People-list, pass a Person to a [Parameter]person in the PersonDetails-component

PersonDetail.blazor:
    - Show the Name as <input>, and call HouseEditor.SetPersonName() if the person gets a new name
    - Show the age
    - Show a checkbox to let the user toggle if a person is a parent in the house. Call HouseEditor.SetParent() if checkbox is toggled.

My current solution is to pass both HouseModel and HouseEditor as a CascadingParameter to make sure the House.blazor and PersonList.blazor has binding to the same data. And let HouseEditor manipulate the models directly. This works just fine for House.blazor and PersonList.blazor because they can bind directly to the cascading HouseModel parameter.
The blazor components are setup to use the bind:get/bind:set approach to be able to read the value from the Model, but update the Editor when the value is changed.
This works very nicely both in House.blazor and PersonList.blazor, because they are directly bound to the CascadedValue which is the HouseModel.
But I am struggling with PersonDetails, because this is a child under the PersonList component and only know about one specific Person.
So when I toggle the Parent checkbox to checked for person #3 the following happens:
1. Call HouseEditor.SetParent(3, true)
2. HouseEditor validates that the number of parents in the House is between 1 and 2
3. HouseEditor saves the new state to the API
4. HouseEditor reacts to the response from the API and updates the HouseModel with the new data
5. House.blazor and PersonList.blazor updates with new updates HouseModel
6a. PersonDetails checkbox goes back to unchecked because it's reading 
    from a Person-instance that is not cascaded from the top. 
    So it never figures out about the new data in the HouseModel.
6b. In case the API failed to save, HouseEditor will set the Parent bool back to the old value.

The #6 is the biggest problem, and I can't figure out how to fix it.
Should PersonList figure out what persons has been updated and trigger the child PersonDetail component to refresh data? This seems the wrong responsibility for the list to have.
I really don't want to trigger a large-scale refresh of the data
Ideally I want each PersonDetail to bind directly to a Person, for example to HouseModel.People[3], and react automatically to changes in the model.
Please advice, and if more information is required, I will try my best to oblige. Also I am going to bed now so I won't be monitoring for answers immediately.

Have you considered using two-way binding instead of cascading values?

I did to start with, but the issue then was almost the same as now... The model had to pass the values on to the Editor for the autosave, and it increased the complexity of the model. Also the binding in the ListItem monitores the Collection, not the specific item in the collection. So when an item in the collection updates, the listitem component still wasnt aware of the change.

I haven't examined your code in great detail, but your problem is a common one in more complex data contexts.  Firstly, I would move all the data into a presenter object/service and then either cascade that or have it as a scoped service.  Get the data out of the components and into a single one version of the truth object.    Secondly, I use the Aggregate approach to control data updates and fire events when things change.  If you built a [MRE] to illustrate your problem I could probably work with that to demonstrate,
